# Does sphinx work without database?

Tags: c++

if sphinx does not require database then how to store string or text in index of sphinx ?

Answer (score 4):

From Sphinx website:

> Sphinx lets you either batch index and search data stored in an SQL
>   database, NoSQL storage, or just files quickly and easily — or index
>   and search data on the fly, working with Sphinx pretty much as with a
>   database server.

---

> Non-SQL storage indexing. Data can also be streamed to batch indexer
>   in a simple XML format called XMLpipe, or inserted directly into an
>   incremental RT index.

So yes it works without database... How? You can probably read the doc... Did you search?